# ColdFusion QOQ, compare time values?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, qoq

I'm trying to execute the below code using ColdFusion QOQ but it's not retrieving any records. I am using time in format "HH:mm" and using MySQL as backend and the original time column has a datatype of "TIME".

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="getCount">
    SELECT count(*) as mycount
    FROM getExams
    WHERE start_time <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#curr_time#">
</cfquery>
```

I am able to successfully compare date values using `<cfqueryparam>`. However, it's not working on time columns. Can anyone help?

**Update:**
There is an open bug report for this issue. See [bug #3551866](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3551866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after many hours of effort, I was not able to find a simple way to compare time values within ColdFusion QOQ. So, here's the workaround that I used:

**Step 1**
To retrieve db columns with Time datatype, use format *hhmmss*.
eg. in my case of MySQL I used:
`CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(db_time_col, '%H%i'), UNSIGNED INTEGER) as db_time_col`

**Step 2**
Within ColdFusion QOQ, convert time value into same format as used in Step 1.
eg. in my case it is: `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#timeFormat(cf_time_col, 'HHmm')#">`

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert date time format with createodbcdatetime()/CreateODBCTime()  function to convert current date and time to compare with DB date and time format column

Comment: I tried below code but still bad luck.  

`<cfquery dbtype="query" name="getCount">
    SELECT count(*) as mycount
    FROM getExams
    WHERE start_time <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#createODBCTime(curr_time)#">
</cfquery>`

Comment: try using this   <cfquery dbtype="query" name="getCount"> SELECT count(*) as mycount FROM getExams WHERE start_time <= #createodbcdatetime(curr_time)#"  </cfquery>

Comment: Still it's not working with even createODBCDateTime. I know there's a solution provided online at [asadesigner.com](http://www.asadesigner.com/16-coldfusion/b033bba6f200c1c5.htm) and I have tried using timestamp also. Still no luck. :(

Comment: your column contains both date time with or only date

Comment: try using this time format it creates 24hr time format of current time #TimeFormat(now(), "HH:mm:ss")#

Comment: Many thanks @swetha for helping to solve my problem. Well i have found an alternative to get the expected results. I had to use `CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(db_time_col, '%H%i'), UNSIGNED INTEGER) as db_time_col` in MySQL query and then used `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#timeFormat(cf_time_col, 'HHmm')#">` to compare time columns in QOQ. I wish there was a simpler way to compare these values.

Comment: @Saurabh - There is clearly a problem with `time` values, so consider submitting a [bug report](https://bugbase.adobe.com). Also, you should post your work-around as an "answer" so it is easier for others to find in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that time without a date is meaningless.  Therefore time datatypes have an invisible date applied to it.  However, different softwares apply different dates to time datatypes.

ColdFusion applies appears to apply 1899-12-30.  This code:

```
<cfdump var="#CreateTime(18,0,0)#">
```

returns {ts '1899-12-30 18:00:00'}

However, when I run a database query:

```
<cfquery name="x" datasource="dw">
 select registration_number, event_time
 from admit_fact

 where date = yesterday
 and discharge
 and datepart(hour, event_time) < 13
 </cfquery>
 <cfdump var="#x#" metainfo="no">
```

I see 19 rows with values like {ts '1970-01-01 11:30:00'}.  As a result, a QofQ like this:

```
<cfquery name="y" dbtype="query">
 select *
 from x
 where event_time < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#CreateTime(18,0,0)#"> 
 </cfquery>
```

will not return any rows.  In the "it's worth a shot" category, even I tried:

```
where cast(event_time as time) < 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#CreateTime(18,0,0)#">
```

but the results did not change.   Like Saurabh, I'd also like to see a simpler way to compare the values.

Comment: If you can determine what your database server is using as the "hidden" date (1970-01-01 in your example), wouldn't it be easier to just use the `CreateODBCDateTime()` function using the default date of your database server and then the desired time?

Comment: We can do anything you want once you know what we are dealing with.  However your suggestion while just as effective as what @Saurabh eventually did, it's not necessarily simpler.